# LNK2028 and LNK2019 error when using dll with no inline code

Tags: c++, .net, dllimport, unmanaged, lnk2019

This is the first time I'm using .NET and its giving me hard time when using more than one project. What am I doing wrong? This is what I did:

1 Create a new project (and solution). A "Class Library" called "Lib".

2 Add file "Comp1.h" to "Header Files" with the following code:

```
#ifndef COMP1_H
#define COMP1_H
class comp1
{
public:
    comp1(void);
    ~comp1(void);
}
#endif
```

3 Add file "Comp1.cpp" to "Source Files" with the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Comp1.h"
comp1::comp1(void){}
comp1::~comp1(void){}
```

4 I overwrite the code of the automatically created "Lib.h" file with:

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H
#include "Comp1.h"
#endif
```

5 Add a "CLR empty project" called "Test" and set it as start-up project.

6 Add file "test.cpp" to "Source Files" of the "Test" project with the following code:

```
#include "../Lib/Lib.h"
#using "../Debug/Lib.dll"//Is this line mandatory?
int main()
{
comp1 component;
return 0;
}
```

7 Add "Lib" as a reference in the "Test" properties.

8 Make sure in "Project Dependencies" that "Test" depends on "Lib".

9 Compile them both as /clr

This is what I get:

```
1>test.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000009) "public: __thiscall comp1::comp1(void)" (??0comp1@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>test.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000A) "public: __thiscall comp1::~comp1(void)" (??1comp1@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall comp1::~comp1(void)" (??1comp1@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall comp1::comp1(void)" (??0comp1@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
```

If I create inline functions this problem doesn't occur.

On forums you find answers about mistakes with including files, but I'm pretty sure I coded everything correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the DLL you have to explictly mark functions and classes you want to export using the `__declspec(dllexport)` directive and thus make them available for import by a client. When you import the class you have to use the `__declspec(dllimport)` directive.

[This document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) shows how to mark classes and global functions in your headers so, that they can be used for export and import.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this indeed works. But I'm trying to create a cross platform GUI library, since I don't want to depend on the API I used before. Is there a way of using functions without __declspec(dllimport) to give the users a more standard C++ feeling?

Comment: For other platforms than win32/.net you can define the same macro to nothing. See lines 22 to 34 from here for a way to make this approach cross-platform. Instead of testing for `OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32` you need to insert your own tests. http://gitorious.org/rastullahs-lockenpracht/rastullahs-lockenpracht/blobs/master/rl/trunk/engine/common/include/CommonPrerequisites.h For Win32 I'm afraid you will have to use `__declspec(dllimport)` when importing the dll. I don't know of a way around it.